# How to convert a Cats Effect Resource to ZIO 2 Scopes?

Tags: scala, zio

I am trying to use the Cats Mongo implementation (https://github.com/Kirill5k/mongo4cats) in ZIO 2.
There is a chapter in ZIO 2's doc (https://zio.dev/guides/interop/with-cats-effect#converting-resource-to-zmanaged-1) how one can convert a Cats resource to ZManaged.

But in ZIO 2 using scopes instead of ZManaged is the way to go.
How do I implement that conversion?

This is the cats resource:

```
def catsEmbeddedMongo[F[_]: cats.effect.Async]: Resource[F, MongoClient[F]] = MongoClient.fromConnectionString[F]("mongodb://localhost:27017")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [toScopedZIO](https://github.com/zio/interop-cats/blob/75407bf4e6a60310b46a769805a6abf45d16675f/zio-interop-cats/shared/src/main/scala/zio/interop/catszmanaged.scala#L68) with:

```scala
catsEmbeddedMongo[Task].toScopedZIO
```

Answer (score 1):

In the context of `mongo4cats` library, you can also use `mongo4cats-zio` module, which provides integration with ZIO 2. Docs: https://kirill5k.github.io/mongo4cats/docs/zio.html